# How to read directory path of the Artifact in Release pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to be able to display a directory path of the Artifact in the PowerShell task in the Release pipeline.
In the build pipeline, the directory of the Artifact is described by the variable `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and if I try to display it
in the PowerShell task using the command

```
Write-Host $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

in the console output, it shows the path `C:\agent\_work\3\a`.
This variable doesn't exist in the Release pipeline and when I run the command

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

in the powershell task, in the release pipeline, I can see all environment variables but none of the variables stores the `C:\agent\_work\3\a path`
How can i get it, cuz somehow the AgentJob knows the proper directory of the Artifact when doing the Artifact downloading process.
Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables), I'd expect that variable to be available in a release pipeline.  It should be the same as $Agent.ReleaseDirectory or $System.ArtifactsDirectory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When accessing build and release variables as environment variables within scripts, you need to replace `.` with `_`. This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables). In PowerShell, you'd access `$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY`.

> Variable
>   names are transformed to uppercase, and the characters "." and " " are
>   replaced by "_".
>
> For example, Agent.WorkFolder becomes AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On Windows,
>   you access this as %AGENT_WORKFOLDER or $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On
>   Linux and macOS, you use $AGENT_WORKFOLDER.

Comment: I tried to run the `Write-Host "$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY"` in both pipelines: Build and Release. The values are different. In Build pipeline i can see the path to `C:\agent\_work\3\s` and in the Release pipeline `C:\agent\_work\r2\a`

Comment: @GoldenAge That's expected. Each build definition gets a separate folder. Each release definition gets a separate folder. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to be able to get the path to the Build Artifact directory in Release pipeline

Comment: The value of `$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY` **is** the build artifact directory when running a release. That is the location to which the artifacts are downloaded. Each artifact is put into a different folder. Please refer to the documentation link provided, as it explains all of this.

Comment: ah ok I see now! at the beginning of the process in the Release pipeline, the Job Agent copies the Artifact' files from   C:\agent\_work\3\a to the C:\agent\_work\r2\a

Comment: @GoldenAge No, that's not what happens. Your build publishes artifacts that are stored elsewhere. When you start a release, it downloads the published artifacts. Nothing is copied from the file system.

Comment: It seems that I had a lack of knowledge how the CI/DI works in VSTS, you are completely right, I've just checked the logs and at the beginning stage, the artifact is downloaded from the link.