# Use Build.Repository.Uri in Release Pipeline (Azure DevOps Server)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to use `Build.Repository.Uri` in a release pipeline. (to pass it to a PowerShell script)

In a buildpipeline:

```
Write-Host $(Build.Repository.Uri)
> 2019-07-15T08:30:51.8695425Z http://138.202.18.216:8070/Samples/Framework%20A/_git/Framework%20A
```

In a releasepipeline:

```
Write-Host $(Build.Repository.Uri)
> The name Build.Repository.Uri was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (if included), and try again.
```

Why that inconsistency?

I also try `Write-Host $(env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI)` because of that: [How to read directory path of the Artifact in Release pipeline in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888139/how-to-read-directory-path-of-the-artifact-in-release-pipeline-in-azure-devops) (I also don't understand the logic behind . to _)

**Is there a way to get `Build.Repository.Uri` in a releasepipeline?**

**EDIT: *Solution***

```
"$env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI$env:BUILD_PROJECTNAME/_git/$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME" -> http://136.202.18.216:8070/Samples/Framework A/_git/Framework A
```

If you set `system.debug` variable to `true`, you can find all predefined variables inside of the `Job Initialize` (Auftrag initialisieren) Report after a build.

If your project or repository name contains spaces, make sure that you replace them in your script with `%20`:

```
$Uri = $Uri.Replace(" ", "%20")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Build URI in the Release Pipeline you need to use the release variable:

`Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildURI`

`{alias}` is the the alias of the artifact source you have in the release

If you accessing variables within PowerShell scripts you need to replace any dots with underscores  i.e. `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{alias}_BUILDURI`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Comment: thanks for your response! I try it out and `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_drop_BUILDURI` return `" "` and `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{drop}_BUILDURI` return `drop _BUILDURI`
 My agent release path: `AzureDevOpsData\Agent\_work\r3\a\FrameworkA\drop\.git`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think in this case the alias will be `FrameworkA`. Does `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_FrameworkA_BUILDURI` return anything?

Comment: Also if you add a variable to the release `System.Debug` and set the value to true under the Initialize Job task you will see all your variables printed out to the logs

Comment: I try a lot of different versions now, nothing works. Isn't there a way to simply take the `{alias}` also as variable? I try out Write-Host `$(Build.DefinitionName)` = `Framework A - v1.1` and Write-Host `$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)` = `_Framework A - v1.1` which is the name of my release pipeline. Is it general possible for azure devops to process a variable when a `alias` contains spaces or special characters?

Comment: The alias is available with the `$env:RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS` any spaces would be replaced with an underscore. Have you tried setting the `System.Debug` variable to print out all the variables in the Initialze Job phase?

Answer (score 1):

The variable **Build.Repository.Uri** is agent-scoped. It can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task. When you add variable `System.Debug` with value true in the pipeline, the init job will log all the available environment variables, which includes the REPOSITORY_URI.

You can try with following variables:

`Write-Host $env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI`

Or

`Write-Host $env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{alias}_REPOSITORY_URI`

Please note that the {alias} is the uppercase of the [Artifact source alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#source-alias).
[image]

Comment: I try both but unfortunately it don't work. Could you explain me which **alias** is meant and where can I find that?

Comment: @MarTin, i have updated my response. Please check, feel free let know that works for you.